# Write a file with Emscripten IDBFS/IndexedDB

Tags: c, indexeddb, emscripten

I'm currently porting a C project to the web using Emscripten, but the one issue I haven't managed to figure out is why file writing using IDBFS doesn't work. This is the simplest possible C code example of what I'm trying to do currently, but it doesn't work, that is, checking the IndexedDB storage in the Firefox and Chrome web developer tools doesn't show `test.txt` at all:

```
#include <emscripten.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE* fp = fopen("/test.txt", "w");
    if (fp) {
        fprintf(fp, "test\n");
        fclose(fp);

        EM_ASM(
            FS.syncfs(function (err) {
                assert(!err);
            });
        );
    }
    else {
        printf("fopen failed.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I build that example like this:

```bash
emcc test.c -lidbfs.js --emrun -o test.html
```

And run it using `emrun test.html`.

This other example also doesn't work, though I'd prefer to use C functions for opening/writing files:

```
#include <emscripten.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    EM_ASM(
        FS.writeFile('test.txt', 'test\n');
        FS.syncfs(function (err) {
            assert(!err);
        });
    );
    return 0;
}
```

That last example requires a change to the build command:

```
emcc test.c -lidbfs.js -s FORCE_FILESYSTEM=1 --emrun -o test.html
```

Comment: Did you use `FS.mount`? https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html#id2

Answer (score 1):

You need to mount a disk to directory before doing any operations on file system.

Something line this

```
int main() {
EM_ASM(
        // Make a directory other than '/'
        FS.mkdir('/disk');
        // Then mount with IDBFS type
        FS.mount(IDBFS, {}, '/disk');
           
        // Then sync
        FS.syncfs(true, function (err) {
            // Error
        });
    );
    FILE* fp = fopen("/disk/test.txt", "w");
    if (fp) {
        fprintf(fp, "test\n");
        fclose(fp);

// your code continue here ...
```

There is same thing in [emscripten tests](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/68c91ca690407632439b7fd0cec3cc5e0ba873eb/test/fs/test_idbfs_sync.c#L172).